# Pausing without using timers

Tags: qt

How can I have a pause between looped plays? I do have a .wav file, and i do want to play it continuously, but I want an X ms pause between each playback. I know I can edit the .wav file and add 'quiet' at its end, but I wanted to know if it can be done programmatically, without using timers.

Comment: When you have unrelated questions, just post twice, don't lump them together.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe the implementation language and environment you are using. Most environments have some form of a sleep function that will pause the running process (for example, C has a sleep function) bit it is hard to give specifics without getting some from you :-)

Comment: Why don't you want to use timers?

Comment: did you try to use sleep function?

Comment: I'm with Roku. That's what timers are for. Do you mean you don't want to lock the interface?

Comment: Oh I can definitely use timers, just wanted to know if somehow I was missin the Qt support for it. My app is a cross platform win, mac and linux chat application, written in c++ with Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to use a [singleShot](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop) [`QTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#details) to do a pause in Qt.  There are some other mechanisms in Qt that use a `QTimer` internally. Some of the alternatives may make it a little prettier, but often are in a larger framework and for a different use case.

Some alternatives that might fit your application include:

You could start a sequential animation that uses a [`QPauseAnimation`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpauseanimation.html#details), with internally uses some sort of `QTimer`.

You could poll [`QTime::currentTime()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtime.html#currentTime) if you are checking something often inside a loop or a `QThread`.  You could also do the same polling with [`QTime::elapsed()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtime.html#elapsed).

You could `#include "windows.h"` or the appropriate library for your platform and command a [sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you don't mind the GUI hanging up during the sleep.

You could set up a [`QStateMachine`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatemachine.html#details) and have a transition animation/timer built in to happen between when your video stops and when you want to do the next action, or have something else show up or start.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.